# Moving to next iteration in nested for loop if condition met

Tags: python, pandas, list, for-loop

I have two dataframes that I am comparing in a for-loop: `df_intervals` and `df_events`.  For each event, the loop checks whether the timestamp of the event falls between all of the possible intervals.  What I intend for the loop to do is for each event, check each interval, if True, append to the list and move on to the next, if all are False, then append False to the list.

```
df_events, df_intervals

(  Var2                  ts
 0  bar 2021-02-10 09:04:31
 1  bar 2021-01-29 05:56:17
 2  bar 2021-01-16 15:59:43
 3  bar 2021-01-25 09:40:40
 4  bar 2021-01-27 16:44:57
 5  bar 2021-01-17 13:28:43
 6  bar 2021-02-03 11:46:10
 7  bar 2021-02-02 11:16:49
 8  bar 2021-01-21 17:12:15
 9  bar 2021-01-19 03:44:30,
   Var1            start_ts              end_ts
 0  foo 2021-02-01 20:29:57 2021-02-02 20:29:57
 1  foo 2021-02-03 20:29:57 2021-02-04 20:29:57
 2  foo 2021-02-04 20:29:57 2021-02-05 20:29:57
 3  foo 2021-02-05 20:29:57 2021-02-06 20:29:57
 4  foo 2021-02-06 20:29:57 2021-02-07 20:29:57
 5  foo 2021-02-07 20:29:57 2021-02-08 20:29:57
 6  foo 2021-02-08 20:29:57 2021-02-11 20:29:57
 7  foo 2021-02-08 20:29:57 2021-02-10 20:29:57
 8  foo 2021-02-10 20:29:57 2021-02-11 20:29:57)
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here, as I am setting `match=False` at the beginning of each event and, if the condition is not met, appending it to the list at the end of the loop.

```
matches = []
for event in df_events['ts']:
    for idx, a,b,c in df_intervals.itertuples():
        match=False
        if b <= event <= c:
            match=True
            matches.append(match)
            break
        else:
            continue
        matches.append(match)
​
```

​

```
matches
matches
[True, True]
```

The desired output is:

```
[True, False, False, False, False, False, False, True, False, False]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should look into list comprehension and `any` and `all` functions. Also if you look at the body if your inner loop, you have `if/else` condition there, and it either `break`s or `continue`s. So the last line is unreachable.

```py
def find_matches(events, intervals):
    for event in events['ts']:
        if any(start <= event and event <= end
               for _, _, start, end in intervals.itertuples()):
            yield True
        else:
            yield False

matches = list(find_matches(df_event, df_intervals))
```

Comment: what is the difference between return and yield?

Comment: The way I see it is that functions with yield keyword in the body, return a generator object, which is itself iterable, in for loops and elsewhere, easily converted to lists.

Answer (score 1):

Adding on to coreyp_1's answer, your match is set to False at the beginning of each interval, not each event as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Your last

```
matches.append(match)
```

Is probably indented one level too deep.  As it is now, the line will never execute because of the `break` and `continue` of the preceeding `if..else` block.